# how to get raw value from an enum which is in an array of any

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums

I've a swift function that takes in an array as `arr: Array<Any>`. In this array, I also have an enum being passed. Now, inside this function, I want to get the rawValue of the enum. But, since this is an array of  - I lose the type of enum.

How can I get the raw value of the enum being passed in this array

Comment: If your array is truly of `Any` and you can't use a specific interface or superclass then you will need to conditionally downcast the element as the possible types and process that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the array element is an instance of your enum.

Here is a sample (TestEnum would be your enum type):

```
func decodeArray(arr: Array<Any>) {

    for elem in arr {
        if let elem = elem as? TestEnum {
            print(elem.rawValue)
        } else {
            print("not enum")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should conditionally cast with `if let elem = elem as? TestEnum` instead.